# Getting error trying to override init method

Tags: objective-c

I have a Square class i'm trying to override an init method, the .m looks like this:

```
@implementation Square

{
    Rectangle *rect;
}

@synthesize side;

-(int) area
{
    return side * side;
}

-(int) peremiter
{
    return side * 4;
}

-(id) init
{
    return [self init];
}

-(Square *) initWithSide:(int)s
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
     [self initWithSide:s];

    return self;
}

@end
```

The error im getting is in the `initWithSide` methode that say:

The result of a delegate `init` must be immediately returned or assigned to `self`

Comment: why have you made a recursive call inside the `–initWithSide:` method? what do you expect from the recursion? the return value should be `id` instead of the `Square`... everything else looks good.

Comment: @holex that was my mistake, instead of writing there `setSide` by mistake i wrote the `initWithSide`

Comment: what about the return type?

Comment: Your overridden `init` method is also a crasher bug waiting to happen, since it calls itself recursively. If you need to override `init` here, it should call `initWithSide:`, passing a default value as the argument.

Comment: and what about the recursive `[self init];` call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines:

```
if (self)
 [self initWithSide:s];
```

Make no sense, and basically means you will call the initializer over and over again. You should change it to do something useful (like set the value of `s`, for example). On a side note, your no-arg `init` method is also wrong. It should be:

```
-(id) init {
    return [super init];
}
```

But since there is no specialized implementation in it, you don't actually even need it at all.

Answer (score 1):

drop off your current init methods and replace them with these (don't forget to update them at the interface scope):

```
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        // do whatever you like to to do here
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithSide:(int)s { // but an NSInteger would be more elegant, and the parameter name 's' also would be better to be like 'side'
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self setSide:s];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct syntax:

```
- (id) initWithSide:(int)s{
   self = [super init];
    if (self){
        //init elements 
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: @vikingosegundo could I use this method to also initialize the `rect` variable?

Comment: Not sure why u ask me and not Tito, but sure you can.

Comment: got confused cause you edited the answer so I see your user too @vikingosegundo